# Calling JavaScript function in Html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript and I would really appreciate your help .
I am coding Hangman using JavaScript, Html, Css.
I was able to genrate random Word ans also create placeholders based on the length. But when i am clicking on letter, i want to run the function which will check if word contains the letter, if yes it will place that letter in corresponding placeholder.
This is how i am generating available letters.
I am unable to run check function upon clicking

Here is the link to [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/maddysin/9Hhuy/),
Please advice!

```
document.write('<div class="letters">');

document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr>');
document.write('<td>');

var alpha= new alphabetArray(); 
function alphabetArray() {

this[0] = "A";
this[1] = "B";
this[2] = "C";
this[3] = "D";
this[4] = "E";
this[5] = "F";
this[6] = "G";
this[7] = "H";
this[8] = "I";
this[9] = "J";
this[10] = "K";
this[11] = "L";
this[12] = "M";
this[13] = "N";
this[14] = "O";
this[15] = "P";
this[16] = "Q";
this[17] = "R";
this[18] = "S";
this[19] = "T";
this[20] = "U";
this[21] = "V";
this[22] = "W";
this[23] = "X";
this[24] = "Y";
this[25] = "Z";
}

var err=0;
for (i=0; i<26; i++)

//document.write('<a href="#" onClick="check('+alpha[i]+')";/>'+alpha[i]+ " "  +'</a>');
//document.write('<input type="submit" ;onClick=check('+this.alpha[i]+'); value='+alpha[i]+'>');
document.write('<input type=\"submit\" onClick=\"javascript:check('+alpha[i]+')\" value='+alpha[i]+'>');
document.write('</td>');
document.write('</tr>');


var words=['acres','adult','brick','calm','canal','claws','coach','constantly','contrast','cookies','customs'];
function chooseWords(){
var ranWord=words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
return ranWord;
}
function fillBlanks(word){
var res=" ";
for(j=0;j<word.length;j++){
res= "_   " + res;
}
return res;
}
document.write('<tr>');
document.write('<td>');

var answer=chooseWords();
document.write(answer);

var output=fillBlanks(answer);
var res1=output.split(" ");
document.write('<div id=1><font size=15 ><b>'+output +'</b></font></div>');
document.write('</td>');
document.write('</tr>');
document.write('</table>');
document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="hangArea">');
document.write('<div class="top">'); document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="left">');document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="base">');document.write('</div>');
document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="drawarea">');
document.write('<div class="rope">');document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="head">');document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="body>');document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="leftarm">');document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="rightarm">');document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="leftleg">');document.write('</div>');
document.write('<div class="rightleg>');document.write('</div>');
document.write('</div>');

f
function check(alpha){
for(i=0;i<answer.length;i++){
document.write(alpha);
if(answer.charAt(i)===alpha.toLowerCase()){
res1[i]=alpha;
document.write(res1[i]);

document.getElementById('1').innerHTML=res1[i];
}
}
}
```

Please guide!

Comment: so, can you tell us what is the problem? or maybe post some code..

Comment: better put your code on jsfiddle.net and describe what you want to get and what you really get

Comment: what is answer.length here 4rm where u r getting answer

Comment: answer variable is randomword.

Comment: post your html code too, or as @Godinall said post your code in jsfiddle.net and give us the link

Comment: Why are you writing HTML using JS? You may use JS to write bits of HTML, but you should **never** use it to write all of it.

Comment: Please suggest any tutorials to learn, i am new to Js.

Comment: Using a constructor to create a single instance of an object that has no methods doesn't make sense. *alphabetArray* should simply be an array literal, which would save a lot of typing. Also, you should create a single HTML string and use one call to *document.write*, creating and writing incomplete snippets of HTML makes the parser work much harder than it needs to (though it may well save the snippets until the function finishes if it's clever enough and the function logic allows it).

Comment: also, your fiddle link is broken

Answer (score 0):

It's very useful to think of the problem in terms of strings (or arrays of characters), after all that's what you're dealing with. Then when you get a working prototype you can mix it with the DOM and its methods, otherwise it all becomes a mess quickly.

The steps and implementation of the game of hangman could be:

1. Guess a letter. if letter exists replace placeholder with letter or else do nothing.
2. Be able to guess more letters until all letters have been revealed.
3. Inform the user of the progress so far.

An implementation of this idea:

```
var hangman = function(word) {
  // String revealed so far, as an array
  var result = word.replace(/./g, '_').split('');
  return {
    guess: function(letter) {
      // If word contains letter then replace
      // placeholder with letter
      for (var i=0; i<word.length; i++)
        if (word[i].toLowerCase() == letter)
          result[i] = letter;
      return this; // chain
    },
    get: function(f) {
      f = f || function(){};
      var done = result.indexOf('_') == -1;
      return f.call(this, result.join(''), done);
    }
  };
};
```

And you use it like:

```
var soFar = function(result, done) {
  // Interact with DOM here
  if (done) {
    console.log('Congrats! The word is :'+ result);
    return result;
  }
  console.log('Word so far: '+ result);
  return this;
};

// Value from the DOM
var word = document.getElementById('#word').value;

var game = hangman(word) // assume word = "hello"
  .guess('l')
  .guess('o')
  .get(soFar);
  //^ Word so far: __ell

console.log(game); //=> {guess: [Function], get: [Function]}

// Play more
game = game
  .guess('e')
  .guess('h')
  .get(soFar);
  //^ Congrats! The word is: hello

console.log(game); //=> hello
```